# Frozen mob - Minecraft 1.17.1

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make some decorative "guard" mobs to stand next to my builds. Here is a command I tried to summon an Iron Golem that is frozen:

```
summon iron_golem ~ ~ ~ {NoAI:1b}
```

The Iron Golem still was able to move, even with `NoAI:1b`. Why is that?

Comment: Could you specify what line you used to make the frozen mobs, and also what is the problem? Do they move despite the tag or is the command itself giving an error?

Comment: like are you talking snow golems or what?

Comment: @user282297 snow or iron goems

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "move". "Move" in the sense of walking on their own or being able to be pushed around? `NoAI` should only prevent the first kind of movement IIRC.

Comment: They move and turn. On a vid i watched they stayed still and didn't turn. @mindoverflow

Answer (score 2):

That is weird considering that the command worked perfectly for me. It is also not quite possible that it took damage and moved because NoAI mobs would not move even when attacked, and they won't fall even if you spawn them mid air.
Make sure that your syntax is totally correct and try the command again.

(ps: NoAI mobs can still be targetted by hostile mobs and killed so add `{Invulnerable:1b}`)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that in videos there is a block that they spawn the mob in, so maybe try that and see if that works.

Comment: like a barrier block?